# Product MarkUp with Excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of product price that i need to markup.

I've tried using with Regular Formula

> **=A1*10%+A1+5,000 = 36,130** (A1 = 28,300)

Is there any way to remove the last **2 Digit** and adjust the price if the price result is **36,130** it will remove the **30 (36,100)** but if the price **36,160** it will adjust to **36,200** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=MROUND(<YourExpression>,100)
```

[image]

Comment: i tried but it didnt change anything, can you tell me in detail how that formula works please

Comment: If the outcome of your current expression is `36.130` then `MROUND()` will round that to it's nearest multiple of `0.100` so the outcome becomes `36.100`. @rullymnh. We are talking decimals though aren't we?

Comment: Not decimal, its a thousand. My bad for using (.)

Comment: Then just use `MROUND` and round to it's nearest `100`. @rullymnh

Comment: Alright now i understand, thanks for the help again!

Comment: Btw is there any way to combine both Formula =A1*10%+A1+5,000 and =MROUND(A1,100)

Comment: Offcourse Just use the first parameter to build your expression

Answer (score 0):

In order to round up to a certain number of digits, this is what I usually do (example of 2 digits):

```
multiply by 100
round to the nearest integer
divide by 100 again
(use 1000 for 3 digits, ...)
```

For rounding, you might use the `ROUND()` worksheet function.

Comment: That would totally negate the fact that you could just use `MROUND()`. Sorry but I fail to see the logic here (with no ill intent)